# How to add next / previous buttons to Surface tablet touch-slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, touch

Using this sample:
http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/iedevcenter/zoomandpan/scenario2.html

...I have been able to set up a nice swipe-slideshow on a Surface tablet. It basically uses the following css styles on the UL and no Javascript at all:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
touch-action: pan-x;
-ms-touch-action: pan-x;
-ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
-ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%, 200%, 300%, 400%, 500%, 600%, 700%, 800%, 900%, 1000%);
-ms-scroll-chaining: none;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
```

However, my specs require that there be next and previous buttons. When I set up the next buttons using either of the following methods, they fail in much the same way. Basically, if I do not swipe, but only touch the next button, everything is good -- the second slide presents itself. If I touch next again, it goes back to the first slide. However, if I start by swiping to the second slide (which works great), then touch the next button, the slideshow stays at slide two. If I touch next again, it still stays at slide two. The buttons seem completely useless. Alternatively, if I start with the buttons, click next once, then try to swipe, it does swipe, but it only swipes forward, not backward, taking the slideshow to an empty screen.

```
$li.animate(
{
    'left': '100%'
}, 500);
```

Or...

```
$li.css(
{
    'transform' : "translate3d(100%,0,0)",
    '-moz-transform' : "translate3d(100%,0,0)",
    '-webkit-transform' : "translate3d(100%,0,0)",
    '-o-transform' : "translate3d(100%,0,0)",
    '-ms-transform' : "translate3d(100%,0,0)"
});
```

Apparently, the CSS that is being altered by my next button is not the same stuff that is being altered by my swipe. But since the swipe is entirely CSS, I don't think it alters any CSS. So I don't know what needs to be altered by my JS to work properly with the swipe functionality!

**I need to make the next and previous buttons compatible with the swipe functionality.** I've tried doing it the other way around, making the swipe compatible with the next and previous buttons, through the use of pointers, but the swipe functionality becomes super jumpy and really bad looking. This CSS swipe is really smooth and beautiful. So I want the swipe to be the standard and the JS to utilize it.

**How can I make the JS onclick or ontouch do the same thing as the swipe?**

What I am really hoping for here is a link to a full slider sample that has clear documentation and uses the Surface `-ms-scroll-snap-points-x` style to swipe, and somehow attaches a next / previous button so that I can alternate between swiping and hitting next and everything works as expected.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using the concepts here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254949(v=vs.85).aspx

Essentially like this:

```
function goToSlide(indx)
{
    var wdth = $lis.first().width();
    var newLoc = wdth*indx;
    $ul[0].msZoomTo(
    {
        contentX: newLoc,
        viewportX: 'left',
        contentY: 0,
        viewportY: 'top',
        scaleFactor: 1.0
    });
}
```

Rather amazed at the lack of good documentation on this.